# How do I know eclipse has already build complete my project (disabled auto build)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have disabled eclipse auto build, So I always manually build my project.

but, it always run silence after the build process if there is no error. that is NO message shows in console.

I have used visual studio c++ for many years. the compiler always show the compiling process to console, that is:

compiling xxxxx.cpp file...
 compiling xxxxx.cpp flie complete.
 build done.

How can I know that the build is complete ?

Comment: click on run and once the built finished the program will be running.

Comment: @0x90 I'm working on a web project. and I checked every build trigger a 'publish'. but some times, it just doesn't work. I have to manually click the 'publish' to redeploy the web app to tomcat

Answer (score 1):

In your source code dir there should be a **classes** folder. I'm a fan of the Details view on windows and there I can see the timestamp for when I did the previous build

Answer (score 0):

In your statusbar in the bottom right corner of the eclipse window all running tasks are shown.

If you don't have any pending tasks, this corner is empty. While the compiler work, you see the current task there.

Comment: When `Project > Clean` clicked and `Project > Build Automatically` was disabled then build will not happen. After some time user don't know whether project was built or not.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Navigator** view and check whether output folder(in my case it is **bin**) is empty or not. If it is empty then project was cleaned and/or not built yet. If non empty then project was built already BUT latest changes to the source code after build was done were not took effect.

If `Project > Build Automatically` option was disabled then it is your responsibility to build single/all projects(Wherever the changes were made) before you start debugging or running the project in eclipse.

I always make this option enabled. Build will take less time in my case even tough I have many projects in my workspace as eclipse uses incremental build type.

Note that:

1. You can check whether the current build is in progress or not by looking at the bottom right corner status bar as said by @Marcinek. If it has some message like `Building XXX` then the build is in progress wait till it completes.
2. You can check the output folder of your project by right clicking on the project and selecting `Properties` option. Check the build path configuration here.
3. If source folder modified time stamp is more than that of output folder time stamp then it indicates that you have to build the project for new changes to take effect.
   See below pic

[image]